# Django 1.7 old style custom user model

Tags: django, post, one-to-one

Could you please help me with Django and custom user model? I'm a new in Django world, so I started to learn from newest version 1.7. In my project I'm using django-allauth package and I want to create OneToOne relationship between standard user class from contrib.auth and my custom model "users".

```
 #models.py 

import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    f_name=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length='30')
    l_name=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length='30')
    birth_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    company=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length='30')
    rate=models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)
    skills=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length='255')
    bill_rate=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length='255')
    contacts=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length='255')
    portfolio=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length='127')
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='/static/img/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

This is forms.py

```
#forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from users.models import Profile


class ProfileForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('f_name', 'l_name', 'company', )
```

This is a template:

```
    {% extends "base_.html" %}

    {% block main_content%}
    <div>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Welcome, {{  request.user.id }}!</p>
        <form id="profile_form" method="POST" action="/accounts/profile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ profile_form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endblock%}
```

And views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from models import Profile
from forms import ProfileForm

def edit(request):
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=user)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()
            return render_to_response("profile.html", RequestContext(request))

    return render_to_response('profile_edit.html', RequestContext(request, {'profile_form' : profile_form}))
```

I built all of this files according by this tutorial:
http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html

And finally, all of this works fine, but when I push Save button, POST form doesn't work. I can't see any changes in database. Redirecting works good, actually it seems that all works fine, but I don't have any data in table (I'm using postgres by the way).

I spent a lot to find the answer and tried almost everything in the internet, but I still have this issue. Maybe I can't understand how it works from django documentation, but I tried the same method and still have a problem.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**
My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'laniakea.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url('accounts/profile', 'laniakea.views.prof', name='prof'),
    url(r'^edit', 'users.views.edit', name='edit'),
)
```

Comment: Can you show the urls.py?

Comment: Your form isn't posting to the view that you show, it's posting to "accounts/profile" which is served by a completely different view at 'laniakea.views.prof'. What is that view?

Comment: Prof is just a template with "Welcome, %username%" and "Edit" button. And 'users.views.edit' is a page with ProfileForm.

Comment: Argh. You post the results of this form to prof. If prof does not do anything with the form, that surely explains why your data is not getting saved, no? You need to actually post the form to the edit view.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your patience!)) As I understood, I'm trying to catch post data before I put something in form. And after that I'm trying redirect to wrong page.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding what you are saying. If you want your edit view to process the form, then the "action" attribute of that form in your template needs to be the URL of the view that processes the form, ie "/edit".

Comment: That's exactly what I mean! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! As Daniel said, I changed "action" attribute to transfer POST request to the same form. And as I discovered, I not created a right instance of User parent class. Actually, I don't need to use them.

```
#views.py

from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import Profile
from forms import ProfileForm

def edit(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/profile')
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm()

    return render(request, 'profile_edit.html', {'profile_form' : profile_form})
```

and

```
#profile_edit.html

{% extends "base_.html" %}

{% block main_content%}
<div>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{  request.user.id }}!</p>
    <form id="profile_form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ profile_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock%}
```

Thank you very much for help and good luck!